# Why do alert/console.log run different amounts with Jquery Drag & Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, console.log

I have the HTML structure below :

```
<div id="table_wrapper">
<div class="rows_table" id="rows_table_row_0">
    <div class="rows_table_row highlight-row-0" id="row_0">
        <div class="rows_table_cell rows_table_cell_small">row</div>
        <div class="rows_table_cell rows_table_cell_small">0</div>
        <div class="rows_table_cell rows_table_cell_small">TR</div>
        <div class="rows_table_cell rows_table_cell_big">sujet ligne_booleen cBackCouleurTab3</div>
        <div class="rows_table_cell rows_table_cell_button"><button id="remove-row-0" class="button_remove_row"><img src="remove_row-25.png"></button></div>
        <div class="rows_table_cell rows_table_cell_button"><button id="select-row-0-col" class="button_select_col"><img src="select_col-25.png"></button></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cols_table" id="cols_table_row_0">
    <div class="cols_table_body" id="cols_table_row_0_body">
        <div class="cols_table_row" draggable="true" id="col_0">
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_small">col</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_small">0</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_small">TD</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_middle">sujetCase3</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_middle">ghj</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_middle">false</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_button"><button id="remove-col-0" class="button_remove_col"><img src="remove_col-25.png"></button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cols_table_row" draggable="true" id="col_1">
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_small">col</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_small">1</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_small">TD</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_middle">sujetCase6 cBackCouleurTab4</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_middle">fghj</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_middle">false</div>
            <div class="cols_table_cell cols_table_cell_button"><button id="remove-col-1" class="button_remove_col"><img src="remove_col-25.png"></button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, with the code below I want to drag divs with class cols_table_row and drop it into other divs with class cols_table_row :

```
var colIdSource;
$('.cols_table_row').on({
    dragstart: function (e) {
        colIdSource = e.target.id;
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("colIdSource", colIdSource);
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("rowIdSource", row.id);
    },
    dragenter: function (e) {},
    dragleave: function (e) {},
    dragover: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    drop: function (e) {
        var colIdTarget = $(this).attr("id");
        var colIdSource = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("colIdSource");
        if (colIdSource !== colIdTarget) {
            var rowIdSource = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("rowIdSource");
            var rowIdTarget = $(this).parent().attr("id");

            console.log("colIdSource = " + colIdSource);
            console.log("colIdTarget = " + colIdTarget);
            console.log("rowIdSource = " + rowIdSource);
            console.log("rowIdTarget = " + rowIdTarget);

        }
    },
    dragend: function (e) {},
    click: function (e) {}
});
```

Here is the log output when I drag div with id col_0 and drop it into div with id col_1. I'm ok with it :

```
colIdSource = col_0
colIdTarget = col_1
rowIdSource = 0
rowIdTarget = cols_table_row_0_body
```

But when I drag div with id col_1 and drop it into div with id col_0, the output is multiplying by 2 :

```
colIdSource = col_1
colIdTarget = col_0
rowIdSource = 0
rowIdTarget = cols_table_row_0_body
colIdSource = col_1
colIdTarget = col_0
rowIdSource = 0
rowIdTarget = cols_table_row_0_body
```

Why ?

[Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egxgshrb/) but with alert instead of console.log, and it works : only 4 alert are displaying in both case, instead of 8 in case #2 with console.log

Comment: What's the question? -- _"What's the difference between `console.log`/`alert`"_ and _"Why do `alert`/`console.log` run different amounts"_ are very different questions...

Comment: When i run your jsfiddle and change the `alert` to `console.log` i can't reproduce the same problem as you. Second, are you sure your didn't tried to drag the row 2 times before checking the console. If not, please edit your fiddle to recreate the problem

Comment: same pinch.....

Comment: @evolutionbox : I have edited the title

Comment: @Carsten & user7417866 : I don't know why the jsfiddle can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Didiermaccormick If you cant reproduce the problem, then im sorry but it will be very hard for us to help you

Comment: I know. Maybe the problem comes from the platform : I'm developping a chrome extension, and this script is running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem leaving jquery and made a 100% javascript code. 
I think the problem came from functions building the ui and then calling the script.
Thanks to all.